# Function not breaking out on encountering return

Tags: c++

```
int min_steps(int target, int move)
{
    int x,y,z;
    cout<<target<<" "<<move<<endl;
    if(target==move || target+move==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
   
    x = 1 + min_steps(target-move,move+1);
    y = 1 + min_steps(target+move,move+1);
    z = x<y?x:y;

    return z;    
}


int main() {
    cout<<min_steps(3,1);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above recursive function  `min_steps`, the `cout` statement has been included to track the recursive calls. Now `min_steps(3,1)` encounters a call where `target=2` & `move=2`, in which case the `if condition` holds `True` & therefore the function is supposed to return 1 & break. But this is not happening. The function is continuing to make calls and thus resulting in `Time limit exceeded` error

Comment: Well it did ended. What are you expecting?

Comment: `target-move || target+move==0` does not mean what you think it means. It's equivalent to writing `(target-move != 0) || (target+move==0)`

Comment: Why do you think the `if` condition holds `true` when `target` is `2` and `move` is `2`? `2 - 2` is `0` which when converted to `bool` is `false`, and `2 + 2 ==  0` is also `false`, and `false || false` is `false`.

Comment: `if (target - move || target + move == 0)` is equivalent to `if (target - move != 0 || target + move == 0)`. Could be a typo, but in any case, that looks like a problem.

Comment: @Brian @Nathan Pierson My apologies, yes I understand what you are saying. But the question did not terminate even with ```if(target==move || target+move==0)```. (I originally intended to post this, edited the question now).

Comment: So, `min_steps(3, 1)` has to call `min_steps(2, 2)` _and_ `min_steps(4, 2)`. Is it possible the infinite descent is occurring during the evaluation of `min_steps(4, 2)`?

Comment: @NathanPierson Oh that makes sense, I realize the problem now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in these two lines:

```
x = 1 + min_steps(target-move,move+1);
y = 1 + min_steps(target+move,move+1);
```

While as you said, the first line **did** return, the second line doesn't return at all. It would keep calling `(4,2)` -> `(5,3)` -> ... and cause a [stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763959/what-is-unknown-software-exception-0xc00000fd-error-and-how-to-avoid-it) (0xC00000FD), unless in your input the `if` statement is already satisfied.

So to fix this you need to add more condition or change the second line probably.