# Creating a recursive function that removes odd digits of an integer

Tags: python, recursion

I just started working with recursive functions and I have to create a function that receives an integer and returns a new number that contains only the even digits. For example if it receives `23456`, it should return `246`. This is what I've tried:

```
def newInt(n):
    dig = n % 10
    if dig % 2 == 1:
        return newInt(n//10)
    elif dig % 2 == 0:
        return str(n) + newInt(n//10)

print(newInt(32))
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
```

Any hints on what should I do to fix it?

Comment: fwiw, recursion specifically in Python (but not necessarily in other languages!) is usually the wrong solution.. curiosity is always welcome, however!

Comment: Where would the recursion stop? You currently have no stop mechanism... hint, if n is 0 you can stop.

Comment: @Julien Once n becomes 0

Comment: Yes except you haven't implemented that.

Comment: @ti7 I'm learning this method on an online course, so I'm trying different exercises

Comment: @Julien could I use a while to do that?

Comment: @ti7 So sad, as I love recursions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Python recursion so expensive and what can we do about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67988828/why-is-python-recursion-so-expensive-and-what-can-we-do-about-it)

Comment: "if n is 0 ..." sounds like using `if` is natural here...

Comment: Yup, that fixed the error, now I have to check why it's duplicating the number instead of doing what it's supposed to do

Comment: @ti7 this is not really relevant. Sure there is a point where it is important to understand when to use recursion or not. But before that you need to just learn how to do recursion, which is where OP is at now.

Comment: @theJohnLewis the reason it's duplicating the number is that you have `return str(n) + newInt(n//10)` which should be `return str(dig) + newInt(n//10)`

Comment: I see, I just corrected that. Recursion is being more confusing than I thought, thanks a lot!

Comment: Also it should be `return newInt(n//10) + str(dig)` otherwise the digits come out in the wrong order

Comment: What is the expected output for `newInt(9)`?

Comment: @Julien why not to do something can be equally as relevant as how it can be done, and both should be brought and cause for excitement! just imagine how much time would be wasted if students went away from their classes without knowing linked lists manufacture cache misses!

Comment: @Nick in that case it would be a 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have no condition to stop recursion - every call to `newInt` results in another call. One way to stop would be to check if `n` is less than 10 and then just return `n` if it is even. For example:

```
def newInt(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n if n % 2 == 0 else 0
    dig = n % 10
    if dig % 2 == 1:
        return newInt(n//10)
    elif dig % 2 == 0:
        return newInt(n//10) * 10 + dig
```

Note I have modified your function to return an integer rather than a string.

Answer (score 1):

You need a base case. There's also no need to convert any of the integers to strings. Here is a working version of `newInt()` that resolves both of these issues:

```py
def newInt(n):
    if not n:
        return 0
    dig = n % 10
    if dig % 2 == 1:
        return newInt(n // 10)
    else:
        return 10 * newInt(n // 10) + dig
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant with `divmod`. Uncomment the print to see how it works:

```
def newInt(n):
    d,r = divmod(n,10)
    # print(n,d,r)
    if d == 0:
        return 0 if r%2 else r
    if r % 2:
        return newInt(d)
    else:
        return 10*newInt(d)+r
    
print(newInt(212033450))
```

Output: `22040`

Answer (score 0):

This is a rewrite of @mozway's algortihm using Python 3.10 `match..case` syntax -

```py
def newInt(n):
  match divmod(n, 10):
    case (0, r) if r & 1:
      return 0
    case (0, r):
      return r
    case (d, r) if r & 1:
      return newInt(d)
    case (d, r):
      return 10 * newInt(d) + r
```

```py
print(newInt(67120593306737201))
```

```py
6200620
```

Note `r & 1` is more efficient for testing if a number is even or odd. `r % 2` performs division whereas `&` simply checks the first bit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to break out dig for each loop:

```
def newInt(n):
    if n:
        if n & 1:
            return newInt(n // 10)
        else:
            return 10 * newInt(n // 10) + (n % 10)
    return 0
```